# Unpacking initramfs

Tags: initramfs

With *lsinitramfs* I see a bunch of files. And this is I've got after run *cpio -idv < initrd.img-4.15.0-24-generic* command:

```
kernel
kernel/x86
kernel/x86/microcode
kernel/x86/microcode/.enuineIntel.align.0123456789abc
kernel/x86/microcode/GenuineIntel.bin
574 blocks
```

How do I extract the file correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Install dracut Deb package first. It provides tool called **skipcpio**:

```
apt install dracut
```

Create temporary directory and extract given initramfs file into it:

```
mkdir ~/temp
cd ~/temp
/usr/lib/dracut/skipcpio /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-25-generic | gunzip -c | cpio -idm
```

Comment: Warning!  installing dracut will remove initramfs-tools and other potentially used and useful packages and will rebuild your initramfs which will moot what you were trying to unpack in the first place.  (At least I found out before I rebooted).  Apparently the trick is: unmkinitramfs -v /boot/initrd.img .

Answer (score 0):

Warning! installing dracut will remove initramfs-tools and other potentially used and useful packages and will rebuild your initramfs which will moot what you were trying to unpack in the first place.

Use this standard tool:

```
unmkinitramfs -v /boot/initrd.img out_directory
```

P.S. It's better to write correct answers in Answers, not in Comments.